# Django EmailMessage not sending/timeout

Tags: django, email

im trying to use django.core.mail to send emails using the default backend and it doesn't seem to be working. I've set up the email credentials, server, and port number in the settings file but whenever I try to run the send() method of an email message the command hangs indefinitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def sending_email(request):
    message = ""
    subject = ""
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['to_email',])
```

**Add this in settings.py**

```
# Sending mail
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='your gmail account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='your gmail password'
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when trying to send via smtp.gmail.com with use_tls=True. It turns out I had the wrong port set. Here's what I'm doing now and it works:

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection
from django.core.mail.message import EmailMessage

connection = get_connection(use_tls=True, host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587,username='YourEmail@gmail.com', password='YourPassword')
EmailMessage('test', 'test', 'addr@from.com', ['addr@to.com'], connection=connection).send()
```